# How can I use static methods in other classes in java

Tags: java, class, variables, methods, static

What is the correct way of using static methods in another class but in the same file? I'm not getting any output when I am printing x;

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        int x;
        x=UserMainCode.checksum(50);

        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

class UserMainCode
{
    public static int checksum(int n)
    {
        int n1=n,sum=0,d;
        while(n1!=0)
        {
            d=n%10;
            n1=n/10;
            if(d%2!=0)
            {
                sum=sum+d;
            }
        }

        if(sum%2==0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're calling the static method fine.  The reason you're not getting any output is because `checksum` is looping infinitely, because it has a typo in it.

Comment: d=n1%10;n1=n1/10;

Answer (score -1):

change the line

```
n1=n/10;
```

to

```
n1=n1/10;
```

and everything will work fine.

Comment: If you're going to answer, please explain the reasoning behind your code.

Comment: no this was a stupid mistake on my part....thanks a lot henry for pointing it out....however i used to think that if my logic was wrong i would get a wrong answer.......can't understand the reason for not getting any output though

Comment: @SatyakiGuha In your original code, you said `while (n1!=0)`.  But because of your typo, `n1` never changed.  The `while` loop was supposed to run until `n1` became 0, but `n1` was never going to be 0, therefore the loop would run forever.  And none of the statements after the loop would ever get executed, including the `System.out.println`.  That's why you didn't get any output.  The program was still running.  Does that clear things up for you?